# Change route in Zend Framework to hide key

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-route

I am building a website with Zend Framework but I'm very new at it and still don't really get it.

I have a URL like:

```
http://localhost/public/directory/category/catid/art
```

What I want is to create a route for the URLto look like:

```
 http://localhost/public/directory/category/art
```

I have done simple routes like:

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $frontController->getRouter();

// TERMNS  ROUTE
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
   'termns',
    array('controller' => 'Index', 'action' => 'termns')
);

$router->addRoute('terms', $route);
```

Is there a way, building on that for me to control the other routes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `category/catid/art` to `category/art`.
Add this method to your Bootstrap.php:

```
protected  function _initRouter()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute('category/:catid', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('category/:catid',array(
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'category',
        'action'     => 'index' // Check your action and controller
));
```

And in controller's action for `category/testid` you can use `$this->_getParam('catid')` for getting `testid`.

Comment: Hi! I tried it but it didnt work. I tried also tried putting where it says controller "directory" and where it says action "category" , but also didnt work.